# Generating interfaces from schema

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, xjc

Does a tool exist to generate interfaces as well as classes from xml schemas? I'm already auto generating JAXB classes from my schemas, but I'd like a set of matching interfaces for external code to compile against. I'm not looking to actually use these interfaces with the Marshaller. It looks like XJC used to generate interfaces + classes, but now only generates classes. I could always create the interfaces manually of course and use a JAXB plugin to force each autogenerated class to inherit each interface, but this is impractical.

Answer (score 3):

I have had success by specifying global JAXB bindings like so:

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <jxb:globalBindings generateValueClass="false" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

See http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Migrating_JAXB_1_0_applications_to_JAXB_2_x.html.

If you are using maven-jaxb2-plugin you just need to include the above in a file with a .xjb extension in the same location as the schema.